# How to do the ERD for an E-commerce site that sells products and product bundles for different-prices?

Tags: database-design, erd

I'm working on an E-commerce site that sells furniture, the owner sells multiple types of furniture but also has the ambition to sell sets of furniture (ex: a desk and a chair together) with a different price than the sum of the set's products individually.
I'm  trying to make the according ERD and the problem here is that the "products" table has a many-to-many relationship with the "orders" table, but in this case there's a "products" table and a "products_set" table

the issue here is that when making the ERD I normally would:

1.create the "products","individual","products_set" entities.
2.create the specialization relationship between the entities.

But in this case there's a many-to-many relationship between the "individual" and the "products_set" table (since each products_set is a group of individual products).
can that cause problems when it comes to writing requests?
How can I model this correctly

Comment: This is a recursive many-to-many relationship. A product can be comprised of many products. Each product set is itself a single product made up of other products. The example used in many textbooks is the relationship between an employee and manager. An manager can oversee other employees while also reporting to another manager. Your case is similar, but many-to-many. When normalizing, you'll need a bridge table in the recursive relationship to manage the many-to-many.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you've provided a very useful information

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034677/tim)'s answer that offered the technical term for the case I'm working on "recursive many-to-many relationship" I found a solution in a DBMS book [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2X9W.png)

as explained:

The M:N recursive relationship might be more familiar in a school environment. For instance, note how the M:N “COURSE requires COURSE” relationship illustrated in Figure 4.17 is implemented in Figure 4.21. In this example, MATH-243 is a prerequi-site to QM-261 and QM-362, while both MATH-243 and QM-261 are prerequisites to QM-362.